# rpm - how to execute a php file in %post rpm

Tags: rpm

I'm creating an rpm installer for a php web application. One of the requirement is to run a php script, an entry script that will update the source, database and execute fix scripts.

To accomplish this requirement, I created a  tar file that has the php script and other files needed for the update and stores it on sources directory. And I just needed to call the php script on %post.

```
%post
cd $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
gunzip %{name}-%{version}.tar
tar -xvf %{name}-%{version}.tar
php install.php
```

I change directory first to build since I think that is location of tar files. Then uncompress the files and execute the php script. But instead I got the errors below:

```
gunzip: can't stat: webapp-1.0.tar (webapp-1.0.tar.gz): No such file or directory
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'webapp-1.0.tar'
Could not open input file: install.php
```

How should I execute the php script? Is this possible?

Also which rpm file should I used to install for final distribution, the one in the directory rpms/i386 or srpms? I'm still developing the rpm.

Any help is appreciated.

[EDIT]
I tried to use `%setup  -c -n %{name}` on %post instead of the tar commands. Then I got this message `Could not open input file: install.php`

Comment: The problem here is the `cd $RPM_BUILD_ROOT` command, that doesn't change the directory correctly, because the other commands cannot find the files correctly. You need to find a correct way to change to the desired directory.

Comment: Why are you untarring the package at %post? You should be doing this at build time.

Answer (score 2):

if this is a .spec file, use  %{buildroot} instead of $RPM_BUILD_ROOT. See the "Macros" chapter here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package

Also try `echo %{buildroot} > /tmp/dbg.txt`  and check /tmp/dbg.txt  contents to see where it tries to cd.

I suggest to try using [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm/wiki) which is able to build all kinds of packages. Just supply the pre-post install scripts as arguments along with the rest. No rpm spec files or deb rule files needed.

Comment: using cd %{buildroot} still gives an error "No such file or directory"